# xslt - Sorting nodes into different divs

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to say that xslt is not one of my best skills :(
I've read a lot about sorting nodes into different groups and i managed to sort different issues into different groups. But my problem now is, that i have to sort the same objects into groups again.

My xml structure looks like this

```
<issues>
  <issue status="open" type="Bug">
    <fix_versions>6.14.0</fix_versions>
    <title>issue1</title>
    <description>Description</description>
  </issue>
  <issue status="open" type="Feature">
    <fix_versions>6.13.0</fix_versions>
    <title>issue2</title>
    <description>Description</description>
  </issue>
  <issue status="open" type="Improvement">
    <fix_versions>6.14.0</fix_versions>
    <title>issue3</title>
    <description>Description</description>
  </issue>
```

What i want is to have a html structure like this:

```
<div class="version">
  <a>6.14.0</a>
  <div class="issues">
    <div class="Bugs">
      <a href="">issue1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="Improvements">
      <a href="">issue3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="version">
  <a>6.13.0</a>
  <div class="issues">
    <div class="features">
      <a href="">issue2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But all i get is:

```
<div class="version">
  <a>6.14.0</a>
  <div class="issues">
    <a href="">issue1</a>
    <a href="">issue3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="version">
  <a>6.13.0</a>
  <div class="issues">
    <a href="">issue2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my xslt so far:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//issue[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('versions', fix_versions)[1])]">
    <xsl:sort select="fix_versions" order="descending"/> 
    <div class="release">
        <a href="" class="version"><xsl:value-of select="fix_versions"/></a>
        <div class="version" style="display:none;">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('versions', fix_versions)">

            <xsl:if test="@type='Bug'">

              <xsl:value-of select="title"/>

    </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each>

        </div>
   </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

I would just need a posibilty to sort the issues inside "" and put them into different div's. That would be enough for me.

Do you have any suggestions? Tried out a lot, but nothing works :( Thank you a lot

Edit 2:

I have some problems with xsl attributes and the dollar symbol with php + xsl :/
Thats what the structure looks like

```
<?php
function releaseNotes() {
 $xsl = <<<EOB

 <xsl:attribute name="version"><xsl:value-of select="fix_versions"/></xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:value-of select="$version"/>

 EOB;
 $xmldoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
 $xmldoc->load($source);
 $xsldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xsl);

 $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
 $proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
 return $proc->transformToXML($xmldoc);
}
?>
```

Any idea, what this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. How about keeping it simple:

```
<xsl:template match="issues">
  <xsl:for-each select="
    //issue[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('versions', fix_versions)[1])]
  ">
    <xsl:sort select="fix_versions" order="descending"/> 

    <xsl:variable name="issueGroup" select="key('versions', fix_versions)" />

    <div class="release">
      <a href="" class="version">
        <xsl:value-of select="fix_versions"/>
      </a>
      <div class="issues">
        <div class="Bugs">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$issueGroup[@type = 'Bug']" />
        </div>
        <div class="Improvements">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$issueGroup[@type = 'Improvement']" />
        </div>
        <div class="Features">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$issueGroup[@type = 'Feature']" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="issue">
  <div class="issue_{@type}">
    <a href=""><xsl:value-of select="title" /></a>
    <div><xsl:value-of select="description" /></div>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

You could of course add another `<xsl:key>` that groups the `<issue>` elements by `fix_versions` and `@type`, but for this case it might be unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply :) I'll try to implement that.

Comment: Hey i tried a simply version of yours first to test if its the right way, but already this doesnt work. I edit my first Post to show what i did :) Any idea, what the problem might be?



Any idea, what this might be?

Comment: @KddC Why didn't you try my code? Also "doesn't work" is hardly an error description I can act on.

Comment: Just figured out, that attributes dont work in my stylesheet...I'm using the stylesheet inside of a php function.

`function releaseNotes() {
$xsl = <<<EOB
//All the code
EOB;
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xmldoc->load($source);
$xsldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xsl);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
return $proc->transformToXML($xmldoc);
}
`

But as soon as i want to use a attribute like $issueGroup the function just returns nothing. Any Experience with that? 

Thats why i changed your code a little, didnt work out of the box, but not your fault :)

Comment: I edited the post because of the code part. Have you ever seen something like this?

Comment: @KddC The "XSL" you load in your PHP code is not XSLT at all. An XSLT document begins with `<xsl:stylesheet>`. If you post code samples, post them in a way that they at least compile.

Comment: Hey, sorry i thought it's the best to keep the code as light as possible if i post it here. If it's better to post the full code. I'll do that in the future. I used a second key now, which worked. But i have figured out the other problem now and will try your code again tonight. I just had an overdose of xsl yesterday ;) I'll tell you if your code works :)